# How to validate ImageField prior to saving to disk?

Tags: django

I'm trying to put an image to ImageField from some external url.

Here is my model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=_upload_path,
        validators=[...]
    )
```

That's how I receive a file from url:

```
from io import BytesIO
import requests
from django.core.files import File

fp = BytesIO()
fp.write(requests.get(url).content)
file = File(fp)
```

and now I need to attach this file to MyModel, if I do like that:

```
mymodel = MyModel()
mymodel.photo.save("some_filename.jpg", file)
```

I can see that the file has been saved to `upload_path/some_filename.jpg` **without any validation** (all validators of MyModel.photo field were ignored)

is it possible to do something like:

```
mymodel.photo = ???
mymodel.full_clean()
mymodel.save()
```

so `some_filename.jpg` appears on the disk only after required validations? I just need to validate the file by ImageField validators and save it to the disk after that.

Comment: do you would like save an imagen into DB ? don't into directory ?

Comment: I just need to validate the file by ImageField validators and save it to the disk after that.

Comment: do you need save a image on external server and get this url and inser into DB ? is correct ?

Comment: I think its duplicate question. Here is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40881708/django-model-validator-not-working-on-create

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I will try to create and fill in  programmatically ModelForm for validation. It seems that I can attach InMemoryUploadedFile to a form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/validators/

> Note that validators will not be run automatically when you save a model, but if you are using a ModelForm, it will run your validators on any fields that are included in your form.

So a ModelForm is needed to validate the model by validators:

```
# receiving InMemoryUploadedFile from url (pseudocode)
response = requests.get(url)
fp = io.BytesIO()
fp.write(response.content)
fp.seek(0)
file = django.core.files.File(fp)
in_memory_uploaded_file = django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile(
    fp, 'field_name', 'file_name.jpg', mime_type, file_size, None
)

# form validation
form_data = {}
form_files = {
    photo: in_memory_uploaded_file
}
mymodel_form = ModelForm(data=form_data, files=form_files) 
if mymodel_form.is_valid():
    mymodel = mymodel_form.save(commit=False)
    mymodel.save()

def get_image_from_url(self, url: str):
    parsed_url = urlparse(url)
    filename = os.path.basename(parsed_url.path)
    response = requests.get(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't is good idea save imagen into **DB** , exist a purpose to the folder **media** but  maybe you can use this **BinaryField** : [BinaryField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#binaryfield)

**models.py**

```
class ExampleModel(model.Model):
    image = models.BinaryField(blank=True)
```

**views.py**

```
def uploadImageIntoDb(request):
    image_file = request.FILES['image'].file.read()
    ExampleModel.objects.create(image=image_file)
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestions. No, I just need to validate the file by ImageField validators and save it to the disk after that.